# Scheme and Merge Sort?

Tags: scheme, mergesort

I was assigned to write a merge sort in Scheme but I have some issues with it. I showed it my professor and he said there is one simple mistake. Can someone help me? 
Plzz!

```
(define msort
     (lamdba(1st)
          (cond
               ((null?? 1st) 1st)
               ((null? (cdr 1st)) 1st)
               (#t ((letrec ((half (quotient (lenght 1st) 2))
                    (merge (lamdba (a b result)
                         (cond ((null? a) (apped (reserve a) result))
                               ((null? b) (append (reserve a) result))
                               ((> (car a) (car b) (merge a (cdr b) (cons (car b) result))
                               (#t (merge (cdr a) b (cons (car a) result)))))))
                   (merge (msort (take 1st half)) (msort (drop 1st half)) '()))))))
```

Comment: Hey Jozefg, did you change anything on my code? Can you explain what did you do? I appreciate your help!

Comment: Its considered bad practice to fix code in the question so @jozefg probably just formatted the code so it's readable by humans.

Comment: @Sylwester Indeed, It was a bit paren-soup-ish. To the OP: adding 4 spaces before your code on each line gives you syntax highlighting + indentation

Comment: I see. I am sorry for asking so many question, but is the edited version now suppose to work?
 if not, any thoughts

Comment: do you see `lamdba` and `null??` there right at the beginnign?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge Sort : Scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20506332/merge-sort-scheme)

Comment: better to close that other question (without any answer too) and leave this one be, with an answer.

Comment: Before taking a programming class perhaps you should take a typing class?  Tough transcribing a homework description onto Stack Overflow, huh?

Comment: @GoZoner :-D I especially recommend typing classes for Dvorak, but I'm biased. (I've used Dvorak for 10 years, and enjoy my leisurely 120 wpm typing speed.)

Comment: @WillNess TBH I chose to close the other one not because this one has an answer, but because this one has a cooler-looking postid. ;-)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young what's a postid? :)

Comment: @WillNess Would it be more readable as post_id? ;-) 20506666 is the postid for this question.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young a-ha! Some of us even have cool user_ids...  :)

Answer (score 2):

One simple mistake? He probably referred to #1, but even after fixing that you have some identifiers and parenthesis to fix:

1. `lambda`, `null?`, `length`, `append`, and `reverse`  is spelled incorrectly.
2. `letrec` result gets applied since you have excess parenthesis around it.
3. `cond` in `merge` where you compare elements are missing parenthesis two places.

It's obvious you need help with parenthesis matching so you should download a decent IDE to write code in. I use [DrRacket](http://racket-lang.org/) for Scheme development (#!R5RS, #!R6RS and #!racket) and it idents (just press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to get it reidented after pasting in code) and indicate where function names are written wrong when you hit <kbd>RUN</kbd>.

Making merge a global function in the beginning and perhaps move it to a letrec later  (if you have to) might ease development. Eg. you could find errors by testing stuff like `(merge '(3 2 1) '())`.

This is no guarantee the program will work since I only address syntax here. You need to debug it! **DrRacket** has a debugger too!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is useful to implement first a function that allow to merge two **ordered** lists:

```
(define (merge l1 l2)
  (if (empty? l1)
      l2
      (if (empty? l2)
          l1
          (if (< (car l1) (car l2))
              (cons (car l1) (merge (cdr l1) l2))
              (cons (car l2) (merge l1 (cdr l2)))))))
```

Now assume we have a function `(get ls pos)` capable to return the element of `ls` in position `pos`:

```
(define (get ls pos)
  (if (= pos 1)
      (car ls)
      (get (cdr ls) (- pos 1))))
```

Finally, we can implement `mergesort` function:

```
(define (mergesort l p r)
  (if (= p r)
      (cons (get l p) empty)
      (merge (mergesort l p (floor (/ (+ p r) 2))) (mergesort l (+ (floor (/ (+ p r) 2)) 1) r))))
```